# Cannot get jQuery Backstretch to work on body

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

http://getfilming.co.uk/ is the link.
I have put

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/img/jquery.backstretch.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.backstretch("/wp-content/img/getfilmbg.png");
</script>
```

just above `</head>` but to no avail!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `<script type="javascript">$(function(){ $.backstretch("/wp-content/img/getfilmbg.png"); });</script>`?

Answer (score 0):

GET http://getfilming.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Bosky/includes/js/jquery.cycle.all.js?ver=3.5.1 404 (Not Found) getfilming.co.uk:10

Because can't find the file jquery.cycle.all.js, you got the next error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'

Just put the plugin there and should work

Comment: Seem to have resolved the 404 issue, but I can't understand what it's not liking this time around?